# Material UI components not working in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code snippet, which doesn't display anything at all in the browser window. Can you please tell me why.

```
render(){ 
    return (
        <div>
            //Rama
            //console.log('In Render'),  
            <div>
                enter code here    
                <div>
                    <TextField    
                        hintText="Username"     
                    />
                    <br/>    
                    <TextField  
                        hintText="Password"    
                    />
                    <br/>

                    <RaisedButton label="Login" primary={true}  />  
                </div>
            <div>
            <TextField>Login Successful</TextField> 
            </div>
        </div>
    )  
}
```

`pastebin` link for complete component: http://pastebin.com/etjUwvWT

Comment: Are you importing `TextField`, `RaisedButton`, whats the error you see.., Share entire code instead of just the render function.

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: The entire code....import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';

Comment: Can I use Pastebin

Comment: update the ques with complete code :) snippet that you pasted in ques, there is a div mismatch, it should through the error, if you are using the same.

Comment: Yes you can use pastebin, github gist, codepen, whatever works for you.

Comment: Also check the developer console for errors, It will tell you why you're not seeing anything and then you can fix that issue.

Comment: No errors in the console.....Paste Bin here http://pastebin.com/etjUwvWT. I can give other parts of the project also

Comment: you are using only material ui component put one more div with fixed text like this: `<div>Hello</div>` check whether its coming or not. will come to know that it is because of material ui or not.

Comment: The code looks alright.., so the problem could be with any if the imported files/parent components, can you take screenshot of your developer console and upload it.. as if there are any errors you should be able to see it, Also are other parts of the app working, are you importing the necessary css files?

Comment: try replacing `<TextField>Login Successful</TextField>` with `<div>Login Successful</div>`

Comment: It works . thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To render `material-ui` components you need to wrap them in `MuiThemeProvider`.

**As Per [DOC](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui#usage):**

> Beginning with v0.15.0, Material-UI components require a theme to be
>   provided. The quickest way to get up and running is by using the
>   MuiThemeProvider to inject the theme into your application context.

**How to use these components?**

First use this line to import `MuiThemeProvider` :

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
```

Use this render method:

```
render(){  
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Username"
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Password"
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <RaisedButton label="Login" primary={true}  />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <TextField/>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

If you are using material-ui components across the project then no need to use `MuiThemeProvider` on each page, you also include it globally. Include this in your router or put this line on main page of the application.

One more thing you are only importing the `injectTapEventPlugin`, you need to initialise that also. Put this line in this component after importing:

```
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having JS-comments (`//`) in your JSX code. That'll make stuff break.

If you want to comment something out in JSX, you have to escape into JS with curly brackets and then use multi line comments (`/* comment */`) - like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <button>Commented out button</button>*/}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Remove all comments from render, also make sure you have it all wrapped in MuiThemeProvider -> make sure you follow the Material-UI tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Remove text from between the `TextField` tags. Also wrap your code in your render method between MuiThemeProvider. 
This worked for me.

```
render(){
  return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
            <div>
              <TextField
                hintText="Username"
              /><br/>
              <TextField
                hintText="Password"
              /><br/>

              <RaisedButton label="Login" primary={true}  />
            </div>

            <div> 
              <TextField></TextField>
            </div>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>

   ); 
}
```

Comment: I am glad I could help. Can you please mark my answer green?

Answer (score 0):

As an FYI, so it is not the most obvious responses, but just in case this is your situation, my issue was that I had changed my Windows 10 personalise settings to use contrast and my blue bar in my React app disappeared! After a while of searching, I switched it off and my bar was back.